# XSL: Placing multiple entries in one html tag without breaking the tag structure

Tags: xslt

My XML source looks as follows:

```
<query>
  <Rows>
    <Row ID="1" name="person1" title="p1package1" />
    <Row ID="2" name="person1" title="p1package2" />
    <Row ID="3" name="person2" title="p2package1" />
  </Rows>
</query>
```

And I want to create an output with XSL like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>person1</td>
    <td>p1package1, p1package2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>person2</td>
    <td>p2package1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried it with the following XSL-sylesheet, but the open  before the first  seems to cause an invalid structure so the page cannot load.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />  
    <xsl:template match='query'>
      <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row" >
          <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::Row/@name != @name or position() = 1">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
                <td>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
          <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Row/@name = @name)">
                </td>
              </tr>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How could I approach this? I know the XML is not structured nicely but I have no influence on the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to grouping problems like this in XSLT 1.0 is *Muenchian grouping* - you define a key that groups your items in the way you want and then use a `generate-id()` trick to process just the *first* item with each key value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />

  <xsl:key name="rowByName" match="Row" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <!-- apply templates for the first Row with each name -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="query/Rows/Row[generate-id() =
          generate-id(key('rowByName', @name)[1])]" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
      <td>
        <!-- concatenate the title attributes of all rows with this name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('rowByName', @name)">
          <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint and detailed example!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness here's the equivalent in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />  
    <xsl:template match='query'>
      <table>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Rows/Row" group-by="@name">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@title" separator=", "/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```